# Share assets between windows forms projects

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-core

I need to know how to share assets like images and icons etc. between windows forms projects of the same solution using `.NET6` and `Visual Studio 2022`?

The purpose is to change those assets in one place and have the changes replicated in all projects.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a class library project.  Project > Properties > Resources, click "Click here to create one".  On the toolbar, far right, change the "Access Modifier" to Public.

Comment: I referenced the class library and accessed those public resources from the other projects by code. That works like charm. Thank you.